# What is the point of 5 minutes comment edit window, if we can delete and re-post?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments, comment-edits

I am aware of the "comment-timeout" which prevents the user to edit comments after 5 minutes edit window.

But, it doesn't prevent the user from deleting and posting a new comment with modified content after 5 minutes.

So, what's the use of that 5-minute comment editing timeout if users can ***delete and post modified comment***, ?